# Как запустить код/файл в PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Создал проект в **PyCharm**, создал в папке файл, написал хоть какой-то код(к примеру *print("hello)*). Хочу запустить это, жму *"Run"*->*"Run..."*, а дальше что? Есть только *"Edit Configurations"* и все. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да не, надо так:

- Кликаешь контекстно на файл, который надо запустить, (там сбоку такая [штука](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZzkt.png) есть)
- Выбираешь Run

Готово.